# How to append HTML form data into the URL as path and not as a query string?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

So a typical HTML form with a get would look like this :

```html
<form action="https://mywebsite.com/mypage" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="myparam" name="myparam">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and takes the user to :
`https://mywebsite.com/mypage?myparam=value`

However, I would like to know if it is possible for my form to take my user to :
`https://mywebsite.com/mypage/value` ? Basically, adding the `myparam` input's value to the path at the end of the url.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess I could write a JavaScript function that redirects the user based on what is in the input, but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create javascript function or you can declare a backend function, and return a redirect to your request route

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    let param = document.querySelector('input[name="myparam"]').value

    window.location.href = 'https://mywebsite.com/mypage/' + param
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Is there no solution to do it in a form?

Comment: Another one you can write htaccess or nginx rewrite rule but you can't do that with form