# Getting an individual item with a POST request form a Firestore database is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore, crud

I have a Firestore application running (Collection: 'students', containing 5 documents)
One document has the id: 1

I can write with a HTML form to that collection, so i can add an individual student.
I can also get all the students in one table (Bootstrap).

But i got lost when asking for the data of an individual student.

if i open a new terminal (VS code) and give the command

```
$curl "http://localhost:8080/student/1"
```

then the requested data are shown in my terminal
{"fatherName":"Terpstra","lastName":"Gerrits","firstName":"Mark"}

However: when i use this form in a HTML page

```
<form id="apply-form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/student/:id">
      <label for="id">Student ID</label>
       <input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="....">
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Get Data</button>
</form>
```

fill in the textfield: `1`, and click the submit button

I get as result : *Cannot POST /student/:id*

If i use `method="GET"` in this form then the result in my browser is: `http://localhost:8080/student/:id?id=1`

If i type in the url:  `http://localhost:8080/student/1`, then i get the requested data
*{"fatherName":"Terpstra","lastName":"Gerrits","firstName":"Mark"}*

This way i could check if the data request to the database gives a result the correct data.

I do not know what is going wrong with the HTML-form, this is what i use in my application:

==== studentController.js

```
'use strict';
const firebase = require('../db');
const Student = require('../models/student');
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
.....
// 1 of the documents from the collection
const getStudent = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const student = await firestore.collection('students').doc(id);
        const data = await student.get();
        //if(!data.exists) {
            if(data == null) {

            res.status(404).send('Student with the given ID not found');
        }else {
            res.send(data.data());
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    addStudent,
    getAllStudents,
    getStudent,
    updateStudent,
    deleteStudent
}
```

========== student.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const {addStudent, 
       getAllStudents, 
       getStudent,
       updateStudent,
       deleteStudent
      } = require('../controllers/studentController');
// in studentController.js staan de functies uitgeschreven

const router = express.Router();

// 1 document aan de collectie toevoegen
router.post('/student', addStudent);

// alle documenten uit de collectie opvragen
router.get('/students', getAllStudents);

// 1 document uit de collectie opvragen
router.get('/student/:id', getStudent);

// 1 document uit de collectie aanpassen
router.put('/student/:id', updateStudent);

// 1 document uit de collectie verwijderen
router.delete('/student/:id', deleteStudent);

module.exports = {
    routes: router
}
```

============ index.js

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config');
var studentRoutes = require('./routes/student-routes');
var citieRoutes = require('./routes/citie-routes');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

// app.use('/api', studentRoutes.routes);
app.use('/', studentRoutes.routes);
app.use('/', citieRoutes.routes);

app.listen(config.port, () => console.log('App is listening on url http://localhost:' + config.port));
```

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj: i do not understand what you mean. I have router.post('/student', addStudent); in my code, i just did not copied it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is formatting the url incorrectly. You can use something like this (in a script on your form's html page) to format the url for your API when the submit button is clicked, and go to the correct url.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    let param = document.querySelector('input[name="id"]').value

    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/student/' + param
})
```

source: [How to append HTML form data into the URL as path and not as a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472364/how-to-append-html-form-data-into-the-url-as-path-and-not-as-a-query-string)

Comment: Hi, i tried this solution and it is working like charm! Thanks:)

Comment: Nice. You can accept the answer if you want.

Comment: :how must i do that? Accept an answer?

Comment: There might be a link or button somewhere around my post. Don't worry about it if it's not there. :)